# How to get two responses for a single request in soap web services

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I need two responses from soap web service where I should get the first response and after some time based on the element (ResponseCode in my case) in the first response, the second response should come. Below are the sample 2 responses I need form the soap web service

```
Response1:

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:req="http://cp.abc.com/cpinterface/request"> 
<soapenv:Header/> 
<soapenv:Body> 
<req:ResponseMsg><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Response> 
  <ResponseCode>0</ResponseCode> 
  <ResponseDesc>The service request is processed successfully.</ResponseDesc> 
  <ServiceStatus>0</ServiceStatus> 
</Response>]]></req:ResponseMsg> 
</soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>

Response2:

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
<soapenv:Header/> 
<soapenv:Body> 
<res:ResultMsg xmlns:res="http://cp.abc.com/cpinterface/result"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Result> 
  <ResultType>0</ResultType> 
  <ResultCode>0</ResultCode> 
  <ResultDesc>Process service request successfully.</ResultDesc> 
  <ResultParameters> 
    <ResultParameter> 
      <Key>EndDate</Key> 
      <Value>20140103</Value> 
    </ResultParameter> 
    <ResultParameter> 
      <Key>EndTime</Key> 
      <Value>210156</Value> 
    </ResultParameter> 
    <ResultParameter> 
      <Key>Fee</Key> 
      <Value>0.89</Value> 
    </ResultParameter> 
  </ResultParameters> 
</Result>]]></req:ResultMsg> 
</soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible, HTTP(S) is one-on-one in the sense that there's one response to one request. There is potentially a loophole you may be able to exploit by using the HTTP status code 100 (continue). Status code 100 means; 'Sofar everything is fine, but more information is coming'. Your client should then continue to wait for the final SOAP response; which then has status code 200 (OK) or 500 (Error). Although in theory it is possible to use a different application protocol (e.g. JMS, SMTP or FTP) to transport SOAP messages, in practice it is usually HTTP(S).

Having said this, I think you shouldn't go down the statuscode 100 route but instead rethink your approach, stick with the 'one response for one request'. The above would be very hacky and tricky to implement.

Comment: To whatever you said is correct, one more approach that I have used in past, send a SOAP request, server responds saying received. When server completely processed it, the either you pull the response again from other server or, server call back to request on its hook, I think those are better approaches.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this approach?